# Eevee evolutions

Tags: pokemon-go

Has anyone been able to evolve Eevee to more than one type of evolution? My first Eevee evolved to Vaporeon, so did my second. My friend now has 3 Jolteons. Is whatever evolves first the only evolution you can get?

Comment: I've read several theorycrafting posts on this, but it seems there isn't a pattern. Maybe you can try evolving an Eevee with a different skill and at a different location from the existing ones, to perhaps increase your chance of getting a different evolution.

Answer (score 0):

The evolution of Eevee is random, I believe the chances to obtain them are equal. You must have had 'bad luck'.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep catching Eevees and cross my fingers!